# how to prevent using space while typing?

Tags: jquery, validation, space

i have one textfield for input some serial number code.i want set this code show alert if someone use spase. it means space is not allowed and just allowed use minus for separate this code. Are you have any idea for resolve this problem? can i use jquery validate?

```
the correct typing:
135x0001-135x0100
```

Comment: Please restate your question more clearly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

To prevent a space in your input element, you could do this using jQuery:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/AQxhT/

```
​$('input').keypress(function( e ) {
    if(e.which === 32) 
        return false;
})​​​​​;​
```

.

```
$('input').keypress(function( e ) {    
    if(!/[0-9a-zA-Z-]/.test(String.fromCharCode(e.which)))
        return false;
});​
```

Comment: how to make this code just allowed for "-" and if user use "@","&","+",etc is not allowed.

Comment: @klox - Not sure what you mean. Which characters to you want to allow, or which do you want to prevent?

Comment: i mean characters that may be used is "-". And that should not be used is "@","&","+".

Comment: @klox - I assume you want to allow numbers and "x" as well. How about other letters?

Comment: @klox - I updated the answer. Now it only allows numbers "-" and "x". Was that what you wanted?

Comment: no..all alphabet is allow..and for the another marking which allow is just "-".may after this you can understand what i want.

Comment: may be i'm just need your first answer.can you roll it back?

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the user can still paste text that contains spaces.

Answer (score 20):

Short and sweet NOT jQuery dependent

```
function nospaces(t){
  if(t.value.match(/\s/g)){
    t.value=t.value.replace(/\s/g,'');
  }
}
```

The HTML

```
<input type="text" name ="textbox" id="textbox" onkeyup="nospaces(this)">
```

Comment: This should be the best answer!

Comment: The space will be shown if we copy paste something into input field.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.noSpace').keyup(function() {
 this.value = this.value.replace(/\s/g,'');
});

<input type="text" name ="textbox" class="noSpace"  />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this js function in an onkeypress event. Here is the js function.

```
function AvoidSpace() {
            if (event.keyCode == 32) {
                event.returnValue = false;
                return false;
            }
        }
```

here is the input element  (textbox)

```
   <asp:TextBox ID="textbox" onkeypress="return AvoidSpace()" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```