# Prevent Spaces In Text Box

Tags: html

On my page, I have a text box that allows the user to enter a string. What I wish to do is prevent the user from entering spaces into the textbox.

```
<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="InputSkype">Skype Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="InputSkype" placeholder="Enter Skype Name" style="text-transform: lowercase;">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Resolve</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Repeat http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3623395/how-to-prevent-using-space-while-typing

Comment: There's also HTML5's [`pattern` attribute](http://html5pattern.com/)

Comment: Is there any other way you can do it without using jQuery (I don't know how to use it)

Comment: If you read Enkode's dupe, the bottom (currently) answer has a jQuery-less aproach

Comment: Ok thanks i have fixed it now